# Label dataframe column with a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column `text`

```
text
'a red apple'
'the apple is sweet'
'a yellow banana'
'a green melon'
```

I would like to create another column `term` by matching it with a list `['apple', 'banana, melon']`

```
for term in the_list:
    df['term'] = bf['text'].apply(lambda x: term if term in x else 'None')
```

The result I get

```
text                 term  
'a red apple'        None
'the apple is sweet' None
'a yellow banana'    None
'a green melon'      melon
```

However, I expected it to be

```
text                 term  
'a red apple'        apple
'the apple is sweet' apple
'a yellow banana'    banana
'a green melon'      melon
```

I sense that it might be because I use a list but I don't know how to make a loop in lambda itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the split method will only work if the strings are the same all the time. you have to switch around the loop and lambda expression like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a red apple',
'a banana yellow ',
'a green melon'], columns=['text'])

the_list = ['apple', 'banana',  'melon']

def fruit_finder(string):
    term_return = 'None'
    for term in the_list:
        if term in string:
            term_return = term
    return term_return

df['term'] = df['text'].apply(fruit_finder)

print(df)
```

will return the matching value from the list

and will result in a output of

```
               text    term
0       a red apple   apple
1  a banana yellow   banana
2     a green melon   melon
```

Edit: The reason you initial program doesn't work is that your loop and lambda are mixed up. You are looping through the terms and applying only that term to the dataframe (ie your last execution of the loop is only checking for the term melon so banana and apple come up as none)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split`

```
df['term'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1] if x.split()[-1] in myList else None)
```

Comment: Does the 'split' separate the last word from the text ? In real data, the target word can be in any position in the text. So the method doesn't work. I'll edit the example

Answer (score 0):

Try with `findall`

```
df['new'] = df['text'].str.findall('|'.join(l)).str[0]
Out[66]: 
0     apple
1     apple
2    banana
3     melon
Name: text, dtype: object
```